# Dropshadow not appearing on background-image div

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with my drop shadow not showing up on my header and I'm not sure if it has to do with my background-image tag or something to do with it being in the div. It's basically my header section at the top surrounded in a homeheader div and the shadow below isn't showing. Here's the css for the header;

```
#homeheader {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 380px;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/zJv1pxt.jpg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
    box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
}
```

The webkit-box-shadow, moz-box-shadow and the box-shadow don't seem to have any effect on the div and I can't seem to find out why.

I'm still very new to coding in general so thank you to anyone who helps out!

Edit: HTML;

```
<div id="homeheader">
            </br>
            <!--Nav Bar @ top right-->
            <div id="navcontainer"> 
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>


                    <li><a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>


                    <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>


                    <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li> <!-- Need to direct -->


                    <li><a href="#" class="myButton">Contact</a></li> <!-- Need to direct -->
                </ul>
            </div>

            </br></br></br></br>

            <!--Main Header/Title-->
            <h1 class="name"> My Name</h1>
            <h4 class="description">Amateur HTML/CSS/JS Dev</h4>

            <!--Two Buttons Below-->
            <a href="#" class="myButton">Contact</a>
            <a href="#" class="myButton">Resume</a>

            </br></br></br></br></br></br>

            <!--Down arrow button-->
            <a data-scroll href="#content"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/DaSBdv5.png" align="center" width="32"></a>       
        </div>
```

Comment: Work fine for me here: https://jsfiddle.net/d218wodk/

Comment: I'm so confused then, I have the exact same thing but it doesn't show up for me.

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm using Firefox.

Comment: Chrome, I editted my html into the main post if that helps.

Comment: And sorry I should state, it showed up in the jsfiddle but despite it being the exact same in my code it didn't show up.

Comment: I put your HTML in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/d218wodk/1/) and still working. You can provide a live link to your site?, or update the fiddle to show the problem.

Comment: Ok, after deleting things until I've found the problem, it seems it has to do with my #content div that included a background-color: white;. That was over-riding the shadow of the previous header. Thank you very much for all this help, is there anything I can do to rep you or something?

Comment: Don't worry about that. I'm glad to help you :) Good look !

Answer (score 0):

The `background-image` property is not formatted correctly. It should be:

```
#homeheader {
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Lato';
color: white;
width: 100%;
height: 380px;
background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/zJv1pxt.jpg');
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
}
```

See the following W3Schools rerence http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: Doesn't seem to effect it, thank you very much though. The picture still worked before fyi, the shadow didn't nor does it now.